# Why do we redirect all "what is happening to my paper" questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, canonical-question

We commonly redirect questions such as ["Manuscript status changed from Review in progress to Ready for review"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/114030/manuscript-status-changed-from-review-in-progress-to-ready-for-review) to ["What does the typical workflow of a journal look like"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like). However they are not similar in essence at all. At best, the answer in the community question is only tangentially related; it doesn't say anything about status changes for example. This question is by no means unique either; see all the questions that are already linked to the community question.

Redirecting everything to the "typical workflow" question is similar to redirecting ["How to nail a Ph.D. interview?"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/113996/how-to-nail-a-ph-d-interview) to ["How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly), country tag notwithstanding. Admissions processes in different countries is probably no less different than journal workflows in different journals + fields.

Are the redirects overdone?

Answer (score 7):

Would you rather them be closed as too specific and go ask the journal? If the answer depends on the specific journal, it is not a good question for us. If it is more of a general question, then the canonical question provides the answer. If there is something missing from the answer on the canonical question, let's fix that.

Comment: Why wouldn't what you wrote apply to the admissions process too then? Take the "how to nail a PhD interview" question - why can't we redirect that to the canonical one?

Comment: @Allure The differences among admission processes are much larger than those among journal workflows.

Comment: @Allure if you want to add an interview section to the admissions question, I would say linking it makes sense. We just don't get too many questions about PhD interviews.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I'm not convinced - there're plenty of books on how to deal with graduate admissions, and those deal with the process as a whole not just a single country / university. If it's possible to treat the process as a whole, it's also (arguably) possible to answer everything in the canonical question.

Comment: @StrongBad the canonical question already has an interview section actually, it's just blank right now.

Comment: @Allure I haven't read any of those books, but I very doubt that they can have a general validity.

Comment: @Allure Were you talking about [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38237/546) when you said the section is blank right now? I am curious about how common is PhD interview given that Skype is popular in these days. Job interview is one of the main topics on Workplace SE.

Answer (score 4):

I would categorise “What is happening to my paper” questions as follows:

- Questions which are directly answered by the canonical Q&A¹. These should clearly be closed as duplicate.
- Questions where the asker tells us little about what happened and what they already know. [Your example question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/114030) is typical for this category and leaves us with the following questions:

  - Did another instance of *ready for review* precede *review in progress?*
  - Is the asker aware of how the peer-review process generally work?
  - Did the asker already make the guess that the peer reviews did not happen or were disatisfactory and either excluded that option or just wants a third opinion?

  Voting to close or closing such a question as duplicate of the canonical Q&A¹ [prompts the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/255554) to clarify why their question is not answered by the canonical Q&A.
  If it isn’t, this will ideally allow the asker to clarify all of the above and leave an interesting question, where we do not need to reiterate the typical workflow – something we did again and again before we had the canonical Q&A.
- Questions where the asker makes clear why the canonical Q&A¹ does not answer the question, but which can be answered by a slight addition to the canonical Q&A, usually by adding some name used for some stage in the process. In that case, there are two options:

  - Answer the new question and perform the respective edit to the canonical Q&A, linking back to the new question.
  - Close the new question as duplicate, perform the respective edit to the canonical Q&A, and leave a comment that it is now addressed.

  In most cases I would lean to the latter option, but if the answer was difficult to obtain, I would clearly prefer the former one.
- Questions which do not fall within the canonical Q&A’s scope, e.g., questions about an atypical case. These should be left open.

My impression is that we mostly get the second kind. However, I also observed users voting to close questions of the fourth kind as duplicate of the canonical Q&A.

---

Some sidenotes:

- > [the community question] doesn't say anything about status changes for example.

  I beg to disagree. There is an extensive diagram how statuses change into each other and text explaining how and when this can happen.
- If you ask me, the main problem with [How to nail a Ph.D. interview?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/113996/how-to-nail-a-ph-d-interview) is that it is too broad. Interestingly, nobody voted to close as such yet.

---

<sup>¹  [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like)</sup>

Comment: The statuses in the canonical question don't deal with "reviewer in progress" into "ready for review" however. I also notice that once a question is closed it's seldom reopened.

Comment: @Allure As one of the active participants on this site, I observe that closed questions rarely get re-opened because the high rep users are seldom to review the re-open queue. Thanks.

Comment: @Allure For example, as you can see in https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/64754 , there was not enough re-open votes in time, the re-open votes expired, therefore it stays closed although I think it should not be closed. What a pity! Did you do Re-open Review  lately?

Comment: @Anyon: Fixed. Thanks for spotting.